# Can't push my committed branch to my cloned github fork, and I can't find my github fork

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm confused.  I'm still new to git and github.

Almost a month ago, I created a fork of the "Gradle" github project in order to work on some userguide fixes.  I cloned the fork to my desktop and I created a branch to do my work on (I'm not sure which one of those I did first).

I'm doing most of my work in Eclipse, using the Egit plugin.

Today I decided I was done with my changes.  I committed all of them, but I chose just "Commit", not "Commit and Push".  I then rebased my branch to the Local "master" branch and did some testing.

I then tried to push my changes upstream, but I realized that Eclipse isn't giving me that option. The "Push to Upstream" option is now greyed out.  There is a "Push Branch..." option, but I don't know what that is.

I also decided to look at my fork on Github to see if I could see something from that, and now I can't find it on Github.  I'm really confused.

**Update:**

I guess it's pretty clear that I neglected to do the fork first, so I only cloned the main project.

So what is the least painful surgery I can perform to get to a sane state?

I imagine this will start with actually forking the project.  Can I then just change the local project to point to the fork and then push to upstream?

If that's possible, note that the properties of the local project have the "remote"->"origin" section, with the following properties:
* fetch: +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
* url: https://github.com/gradle/gradle.git

Would I just change the url property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm not sure which one of those I did first

The more likely scenario is that you cloned your repo locally and used Egit to create a new branch (which is a great habit, kudos for doing that if you are new to git :) )

I am not familiar with EGit but it seems like it doesn't know where to push :

- Push to upstream : push your local branch to the remote, updating the remote branch set as the upstream of your local branch.
- Push branch : push your local branch to the remote, if there is no upstream set, create a new remote branch which will be your new upstream-branch for your local branch.

As for your last point : if it is not displayed at that URL, it means it does not exist anymore :

```
https://github.com/{your_name}?tab=repositories
```

A solution would be to just refork it and update your remote URL.

**Update:**

After forking the main project, you will just have to change your remote URL :

```
git remote set-url origin {your_fork_url}
```

Don't forget to rebase your work to the latest `origin/master` after that. You should now be able to `push` your branch without any issue.

Comment: Yeah, it seems pretty clear I don't have that forked repo.  I guess I never actually forked it.  I updated the post with more questions about how to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess it's pretty clear that I neglected to do the fork first, so I
>   only cloned the main project.
>
> So what is the least painful surgery I can perform to get to a sane
>   state?

First, make sure that you've actually forked the Gradle repository. There should be a repository at http://github.com/my-github-username/gradle if your username is `my-github-username`.

Then, assuming your GitHub username is `my-github-username` and the branch you're working on is called `my-branch-name`, I'd recommend:

1. `git remote add my-github-username git@github.com:my-github-username/gradle.git`
2. `git push my-github-username my-branch-name`

#1 adds your fork to your repository's origins, and #2 pushes your changes into your fork's branch. From there, you should be able to visit your GitHub fork and there'll be a prompt saying that you can create a pull request.